Spring4d Marshmallow entity with composite key
How to map entities with composite keys in spring4d marshmallow and how to work with the Save/Insert/Update/Delete methods? I didn't find any examples in the library's example projects.
I look in souces example and i not find any example of code with implementation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
